# Trying to run sed command using as pattern lines from other file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to run the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read data; do
      echo $data;
      sed -n -e '/$data/,/reason/ p' logfile >> output-$data.txt
done <hosts
```

The script runs well, without errors, but for some reason I don't know why the sed command doesn't work as it should be. The output files are all empty.

Comment: Because there's no pattern `$data` in the logfile. Wrong quoting (use double quotes instead).

Comment: @fedorqui thank you!